# Перехожу с PHP на Spring (java фреймворк)

Tags: java

Я почти выучил Spring. Фреймворк в на котором можно писать серверную часть сайта на java.
У меня есть сайт. Я на нем реализовал неплохой личный кабинет. И впринципе, сайт написан на PHP.
Я уже переписал весь сайт с PHP на Java.
**ВОПРОС:** Как мне опубликовать spring web приложение(сайт) на мой хостинг?

Сам домен и хост у меня на REG.RU. А там только ASP.NET, и то из-за санкций вроде нет больше поддержки windows серверов.
Публиковать я хочу как и обычно через SFTP.
Объясните, пожалуйста, как мне выбрать такой хостинг, чтобы смог поддерживать java а не php.
(возможно ответ Heroku но там тоже проблемы)

Или какие темы мне нужно понять чтобы я смог на моем (уже имеющемся) сайте, запустить сайт но уже на java?

Comment: Совет: научитесь выделять главные мысли в своей проблеме и только их и писать. Потому что все эти предыстории что вы выучили, на чём когда-то что-то писали, где что делали и прочее - не относятся к делу совсем абсолютно. Просто добавляет ненужной воды.....ну и заголовок соответственно тоже должен быть корректный, типа "Как запустить сайт на spring framework на хостинге"

Answer (score 3):

Просто посмотрите в сторону vps/vds и делайте со своими проектами что хотите. Это в разы удобнее, тк сможете сами управлять версиями, выводить проект в кубер или что вам еще вздумается

Comment: Данил дело говорит. на том же reg ru есть облачные сервера